# Movie where a guy is sent to a sandy planet where time moves really fast but slow to the outside observer

Tags: story-identification, movie

All I remember is the guy was sent to a planet to test something or he did something illegal, and time moved really fast on the planet but slow to the outside world. He had to fix something to leave the planet I think. His dad was also dying and he checked how many days he had left every day, but in the end his dad didn't actually die as time was fast. It took place on a sandy planet.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  When did you see this movie?  Theatre or TV?  What language was it in?  Just to clarify; time passed faster on the planet than it did outside, so an hour off-planet corresponded to several hours on-planet, correct?

Comment: I remember seeing it on my TV and I know it was a movie. I am 99% certain it was in English, but I do not completely remember. Time passed faster on the planet than the outside, as in years on the planet were days to the outside. If I remember, I think the people in this movie were going to use the planet as a sort of punishment, as someone could serve a hundred years or do a hundred years work in a couple days.

Comment: Hi Kalea! I think what would help to know is what year did you see this on your TV? When you're done, feel free to checkout out [tour] when you're able :D

Comment: I checked it out! I would like to see it was in the past couple years, maybe 2017 onward.

Comment: I guess someone should mention the time dilation in [Interstellar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstellar_(film)).

Comment: Similar to Interstellar in that way, but that.s where it ends. My problem is whenever I search up stuff on google, Interstellar always pops up. I'm hoping the part about the dad dying in a set amount of days helps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Could be [Arrowhead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrowhead_(2015_film)) (also known as Alien Arrival) from 2015.

Selected bits of the summary (emphasis mine):

> While escaping a political prison on a mining colony, Kye Cortland is forced to amputate his foot to save himself and the other prisoners from being torn apart by the mining machinery. Cortland is recruited to join the rebellion against General Lang, who won a civil war against General Hatch. **Hatch explains to Cortland that his father, an important figure to the rebellion, is scheduled to be executed in several months on the anniversary of Lang's victory**. Hatch wants Cortland, an accomplished pilot, to hijack a scientific vessel, retrieve its data, and use it to help Hatch free Cortland's father. Cortland receives a cybernetic foot and agrees.

> Cortland escapes in a shuttle, **landing near the escape pods on a desert moon**.

> He then finds out that Hollis left the planet with another pod. Grateful, RE3F illegally grants Cortland access to confidential information, **revealing that the moon is the subject of a relativistic time dilation experiment**. Hatch and Lang want to use the planet offensively against each other's forces.
> Hatch lands on the moon, explaining that 20 minutes have passed from his point of reference.

YouTube Trailer (father and time dilation not mentioned/shown):

Comment: Keyword search on [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/search/keyword/?keywords=time-dilation) for time dilation gave a list, this was #25 and seemed like it fit the bill.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have spent all day looking for this movie!

Comment: Funny, I've seen this twice and I don't even remember the time dilation aspect, just the prison rescue and the drama on the sandy moon.